# Proving if a function is an upper bound

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Let $f(n) = (\log n)^n$
   and   $g(n) = n^2$

By taking a large value, I could make out that $f(n) > g(n)$ .

I want to know if $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ . For proving this, I need to find out the value of $c$ such that
$f(n) \le c \cdot g(n)$ .

How do I find the value of $c$ ? By seeing the function it seems like no $c$ exists. But I am not able to prove or disprove it.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at the plot we can easily see, that these two complexities are completely different.

[image: Plot log log n vs n^2]

To prove it, we have to show that there doesn't exist a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$(\log n)^n \le c \cdot n^2$$

We can take the $\log$ 
$$n\cdot \log\log n \le \log c + 2\log n$$
Because $3 \le \log\log n$ and $\log n \le n$ for big $n$, also the following inequalities have to hold:

$$3n \le n\cdot \log\log n \le \log c + 2\log n \le \log c + 2n$$

And therefore also the following inequaltiy has to hold:

$$3n \le \log c + 2n$$

This implies $n \le \log c$ or $e^n \le c$. And there is no $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $c \ge e^n$ for all $n$

---

The proof is probably way too complicated, but it was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: For $n$ large enough, $\log n\ge 2$, so $(\log n)^n\ge 2^n = \omega(n^2)$.