# How to solve T(n)=2T(√n)+log n with the master theorem?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve the recurrence $$T(n)=2T(\sqrt{n})+\log n$$ using the master theorem. Which case applies here?

Answer (score 10):

Let us actually use the master theorem.

Define $S(n) = T(e^n)$ for all $n$. Then
  $$S(n) = T(e^n) = 2T(\sqrt{e^n}) + \log(e^n) = 2T(e^{n/2}) + n = 2S(n/2) + n$$
Now we can apply the second case of [the master theorem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/91753) to $S(n)$ for $a = b = 2$ and $f(n) = n$ to obtain
  $$ S(n) = \Theta(n\log n)$$
So for $n\gt0$,
  $$ T(n) = S(\log n) = \Theta(\log n \log\log n)$$

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in the other answer, the Master Theorem does not apply here.

To solve this recurrence, we can follow the similar steps in [Solving recurrence relation with square root](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80076/solving-recurrence-relation-with-square-root).

For $n=2^m$, we have $$T(2^m)=2T(2^{m/2})+m.$$

Define $S(m)=T(2^m)$. Hence, we have:

$$S(m)=2S(m/2)+m.$$

Developping the recurrence (or you can apply the Master Theorem for $S(m)$), we obtain

$$\begin{align}S(m)&=2S(m/2)+m\\&=2(2S(m/4)+m/2)+m\\&=4S(m/4)+2m\\&=8S(m/8)+3m\\&\;\,\vdots\\&=2^{i}S(m/2^i)+im\end{align}$$

For $i=\log m$, we have:

$$\begin{align}S(m)&=mS(1)+m\log m\\&=mT(2)+m\log m\end{align},$$
or equivalently,

$$\begin{align}T(n)&=T(2)\log n+\log n \log\log n\end{align}$$

I think we can say that $$T(n)=O(\log n\log\log n).$$

Answer (score 2):

The master theorem only applies to recurrences of the form
$$T(n)=a\,T(n/b) + f(n)\,.$$
It says nothing about your recurrence. Our [reference question on solving recurrences](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/9550) gives details of alternative techniques.

Comment: You might want to check my answer where I do use master theorem.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Sure, if you change variables to get a different recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The Master Theorem states for $a \geq 1$, $b > 1$ and a function $f(b)$, let the recurrence relation be defined as follows
\begin{equation}
 T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}) + f(n)
\end{equation}
We can distinguish three cases:\\
1- If $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b(a-\epsilon)})$, for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.\
2-If $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log n)$.\
3- If $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_b(a+\epsilon)})$, for some constant $\epsilon > 0$ and if $af(n/b) \leq cf(n)$, fpr some $c < 1$ and all sufficiently large $n$ then $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.\

You have 
$$T(n)=2T(\sqrt{n})+\log n$$
Do a change of variable 
$$n = e^m$$ 
So
$$T(e^{2m})  = 2T(e^{m/2}) + m$$
Let $$G(m) = T(e^m)$$ 
Then
$$G(2m) = 2G(m)+ m$$
or
$$G(m) = 2G(\frac{m}{2})+ \frac{m}{2}$$
where $a = b = 2$ and $f(m) = \frac{m}{2}$.
Since $f(m) = O(m) = O(m^{\log_2(2)})$, then we are at the second case, hence
\begin{equation}
 G(m) = T(e^m) = \Theta(m^{\log_2(2)} \log m) = \Theta(m\log m)
\end{equation} 
 Now replace $m = \ln n$ since $n = e^m$, so 
\begin{equation}
 G(\ln n) = T(e^{\ln n}) = \Theta(\ln n\log \ln n)
\end{equation} 
Hence 
\begin{equation}
 T(n) =\Theta(\ln n\log \ln n)
\end{equation}

Comment: OK but we already have two answers saying "change variables to $c^m$, solve that recurrence and substitute to get $T(n)=\Theta(\log n\log \log n)$. So what does your answer add? (And note that your form of the answer confusingly uses different bases in the logarithms: the suppressed constant factors in the big-Theta notation let you change all the bases to be the same.)

Answer (score 0):

The above question could be solved using iterative method also.

\begin{align}
T(n)=2T(n^{1/2})+\log(n)\label{eq1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
is given.

\begin{align}
T(n^{1/2})=2T(n^{1/4})+\log(n^{1/2}).\label{eq2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

By substituting $T(n^{1/2})$ in \eqref{eq1} we get

\begin{align}
&T(n)=2(2T(n^{1/4})+\log(n^{1/2}))+\log(n),\\
&T(n)=   2\times2T(n^{1/4})+2\log(n^{1/2})   +    \log(n).
\end{align}

Here it is clear that $2\log(n^{1/2})=2\times1/2\times\log(n)=\log n$.
Hence $T(n)$ becomes

\begin{align}
4T(n^{1/4})+\log(n)+  \log(n)= 2^2\times T(n^{1/4})+2\log(n)\label{eq3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

Also by substituting $T(n^{1/4})$ in \eqref{eq3} we get

$$T(n)=2^3\times T(n^{1/8})+3\log(n).$$

Now on generalizing \eqref{eq3} we get

\begin{align}
T(n)=2^k\times T(n^{1/2^k})+k\log(n).\label{eq4}\tag{4}
\end{align}

Now assuming base condition as $T(1)=2$.

For base condition we need to substitute $(n^{1/2^k} = 2)$.

Applying $\log_2$ on both sides,

\begin{align}
&(1/2^k)\times\log_2n = \log_2(2),\\
&\log_2n=2^k, \label{eq5}\tag{5}\\
&k=\log_2(\log_2n).\label{eq6}\tag{6}\\
\end{align}

Now substituting \eqref{eq5}, \eqref{eq6} in \eqref{eq4} we get,

$$T(n)=\log_2n\times T(1)+\log_2(\log_2n)\log n$$

where $T(1)=2$ by assumption.

Now we can say that $T(n)=O(\log n\log_2(\log_2n))$.